# Multi-step Programmable Comercial Convection Oven

Tags: baking, oven, convection

I have some [Turbofan convection ovens](http://www.turbofanoven.com/product-E32D4_2.html) which I use for baking. They have a program mode but it only supports one time and temperature setting. What I really need is to be able to create a program with 3 steps: hot, warm, hot, with tight control of the fan speed, time and temperature of each step.

There seems to be a [new version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeqpsnzRCDQ) of this oven which has a touchpad for programming up to 5 steps, although it only has a two speed fan, not a variable-speed fan like the old model.

Do you have any experience with the new version of the oven and does the fan speed pulsing feature make up for the lack of variable speed control?

Or, can you recommend another oven which supports: at least a 3 step program; preferably variable speed fan control; is value priced?

Or, have you hooked an arduino up to your manual oven and have plans to share?